# how to show two input fields next to each other in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, buddypress

I try to get just two input fields next to eacht other. I have six input fields. And four are in line with each other. But there are two are not in line. I just cant fix this.

So this is my css:

```
.register-section-form, .editfield.field_3.field_gebruikersnaamnickname,.bb-signup-field.signup_email   {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 14px;
} 



.bb-signup-field.signup_password,
.bb-signup-field.signup_password_confirm {

  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 48.8%;
  grid-column-gap: 14px;
}
```

So it is about nickname and email. They are not inline.

I just can't fix that.

So it looks like this:

[image]

This is the html:

```
<form action="" name="signup_form" id="signup-form" class="standard-form signup-form " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div>
      <div class="register-section default-profile" id="basic-details-section">
      </div>
      <!-- #basic-details-section -->
      <div class="register-section extended-profile  register-section-form  " id="profile-details-section">
         <div  class="editfield field_1 field_voornaam field_order_0 required-field visibility-public field_type_textbox" data-index="0" ">
            <fieldset>
               <div>
                  <legend id="field_1-1">
                     <style>{font-family:bold}</style>
                     Voornaam                                               
                  </legend>
                  <input  id="field_1" name="field_1" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="field_1-1" aria-describedby="field_1-3">
               </div>
            </fieldset>
         </div>
         <div  class="editfield field_2 field_achternaam field_order_1 required-field visibility-public alt field_type_textbox" data-index="1" ">
            <fieldset>
               <div>
                  <legend id="field_2-1">
                     achternaam                                             
                  </legend>
                  <input  id="field_2" name="field_2" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="field_2-1" aria-describedby="field_2-3">
               </div>
            </fieldset>
         </div>
         <div  class="editfield field_3 field_gebruikersnaamnickname field_order_2 required-field visibility-public field_type_textbox" data-index="2" ">
            <fieldset>
               <div>
                  <legend id="field_3-1">
                     Gebruikersnaam(nickname)                                               
                  </legend>
                  <input  id="field_3" name="field_3" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="field_3-1" aria-describedby="field_3-3">
               </div>
            </fieldset>
         </div>
         <input type="hidden" name="signup_profile_field_ids" id="signup_profile_field_ids" value="1,2,3" />
      </div>
      <!-- #profile-details-section -->
      <div class="bb-signup-field signup_email">
         <label for="signup_email">Email </label><input type="email" name="signup_email" id="signup_email"  value=""   aria-required="true" />          
         <div id="email-strength-result"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bb-signup-field signup_password">
         <label for="signup_password">Password </label>
         <div class="bb-password-wrap"><a href="#" class="bb-toggle-password"><i class="bb-icon-eye"></i></a><input type="password" name="signup_password" id="signup_password"  class="password-entry" value=""   aria-required="true" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" /></div>
         <div id="pass-strength-result"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bb-signup-field signup_password_confirm">
         <label for="signup_password_confirm">Confirm Password </label>
         <div class="bb-password-wrap"><a href="#" class="bb-toggle-password"><i class="bb-icon-eye"></i></a><input type="password" name="signup_password_confirm" id="signup_password_confirm"  class="password-entry-confirm" value=""   aria-required="true" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" /></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- //.layout-wrap -->  
</form>
```

Comment: Use flexbox for displaying items in one row.

Comment: How? I tried almost everything. Because it appears the three upper input fields: voornaam, achternaam, nickname are in one group.

Comment: Can't say more based on CSS code alone. Add relevant HTML also, so that we can reproduce your issue (images don't count)

Comment: this is the link to JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a87L5vmf/

Comment: Check your fiddle, red means that there are errors. Clean up your HTML, you have some unclosed `"` in your code.

Comment: it is from wordpress buddyboss theme the register.php. SO it is automaticlly generated The thml. Oke, I posted the whole generated html file. But that is to much. And I just posted here the most important html :  https://jsfiddle.net/1r0wLfqx/

Comment: You can still cleanup automatically generated code. Or use a different code generator. But as it is now this HTML is not free from errors. Also check the HTML structure for your new input fields, if I'm not mistaken this is different then what you already have.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your provided HTML using Flex: https://jsfiddle.net/r4wjczn6/

```css
.register-section{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.editfield {
  width: 100%;
}

.field_1, .field_2{
  width: 50%;
}
```

Based on your provided HTML using Grid: https://jsfiddle.net/jqL2d941/

```css
.register-section{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.editfield {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.field_1{
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
}

.field_2{
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you. But what I mean is that voornaam and achternaam on same line, nickname and email on same line and password and confirm password on same line. in the examples you posted. I don;t see that. I see only voornaam and achternaam on the same line

Comment: That's nearly impossible without using some form of absolute positioning.
`.field_gebruikersnaamnickname` and `.signup_email` are in different `div`'s.
You need to put both fields in the same section. Then you could position them within that section.

Comment: But the problem is that it is auto generated from wordpress. It is the register.php file: E:\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\buddyboss-platform\bp-templates\bp-nouveau\buddypress\members

Comment: I understand it is auto generated. But to prevent an extend discussion here in the comment, I would suggest referencing the official buddyboss documentation.

Comment: Of course I looked for that. But I can't find anything about it. So crappy documentation. I can't find where the html is generated. They say in the header.php. But I don't see that

Comment: Excuse me for the late response, but this seems out of the scope of the question. You can try and ask the support channel of Buddyboss to help you.